# why does the value of the return variable change?

Tags: c, return

I'm working on a linux proxy program and I'm stuck with this problem. This is the code I'm struggling with.

```
while(n = Rio_readlineb_w(&rio_client, buf, MAXLINE) > 0){
  printf("%d\n", n);
  Rio_writen_w(serverfd, buf, n);
}
```

This is the wrapper function of 'Rio_readlineb_w'

```
ssize_t Rio_readlineb(rio_t *rp, void *usrbuf, size_t maxlen)
{
  ssize_t rc;
  if((rc = rio_readlineb(rp, usrbuf, maxlen)) < 0 )
  printf("Rio_readlineb error");
  printf("%d\n", rc);
  return rc;
}
```

Variable 'rc' means the number of characters read by the rio_readlineb function. Using the printf inside the wrapper function, I checked that rc is exactly the number of characters read. However, the variable 'n' of the upper while statement is always 1. I can't find out what's wrong. Do you think the return value changed some how?

Comment: Avoid using the assignment operator inside conditions, as doing so is a well-known cause of numerous bugs. There is rarely ever a situation where you need to do that.

Comment: @Lundin: I find that actually more readable than `while ( true ) ... if () break;`. However, the comparison should be swapped, so the assignment is on the right of the comparison operator and the assignment should be parenthesized.

Comment: @Olaf Alternatively you could put an extra call outside the loop, which is arguably a bit strange too. `n=func(); while(n > 0){... n=func();}` There's no ideal way to handle loops like this, you'll get stuck with one bad practice or the other.

Comment: @Olaf I would _not_ recommend swapping the order of the operands however ("the yoda conditions"). It's some obscure practice from the 80s, before Turbo C came with the revolutionary warning "possible incorrect assignment" in 1990. Since then every half-decent compiler warns against assignment inside conditions, so there's no need to obfuscate the code. `while(0 < (n = func())` is probably the least readable way to rewrite the code.

Comment: @Lundin: I agree about readability (and I know about the warning, at least by gcc, the name, i did not know, however:-). However. there are two advantages: the first I assume less relevant, and the second being out of discussion: The uncommon optics signal some caution is required. The second: some engineers of my customers want it that way (and it is still more readable than the alternative). I will think about the first case; I was not sure every modern compiler actually warns. Are you sure about major embedded compilers?).

Comment: @Olaf Only one way to find out, try it. For embedded systems, at least the ones I'm using warn (gcc and Freescale Codewarrior). If you don't trust the compiler to warn, you could consider using a MISRA checker, since assignment inside conditions is banned by MISRA-C.

Comment: @Lundin: As I do not conform to MISRA intentionally(1), that makes little sense. (1): I use some some advanced constructs and in some places I also do not hesitate to use forbidden features (yes, I am not a friend of programming like MISRA - but it is a very good idea to read it carefully). Adn my favorite compiler is gcc anyway, fully augmented (warnings on).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's an issue of operator precedence.

```
while(n = Rio_readlineb_w(&rio_client, buf, MAXLINE) > 0){
```

should be:

```
while((n = Rio_readlineb_w(&rio_client, buf, MAXLINE)) > 0){
```

Otherwise, you're assigning the result of the comparison (0 or 1) to `n`.

Answer (score 1):

```
while(n = Rio_readlineb_w(&rio_client, buf, MAXLINE) > 0){
  printf("%d\n", n);
  Rio_writen_w(serverfd, buf, n);
}
```

Is the same as:

```
while (n = /* assignment has low priority */
          (Rio_readlineb_w(&rio_client, buf, MAXLINE) > 0)
       ) {
  printf("%d\n", n);
  Rio_writen_w(serverfd, buf, n);
}
```

I suspect you want:

```
while ((n = Rio_readlineb_w(&rio_client, buf, MAXLINE)) > 0) {
  printf("%d\n", n);
  Rio_writen_w(serverfd, buf, n);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
n = Rio_readlineb_w(&rio_client, buf, MAXLINE) > 0
```

is parsed as

```
n = (Rio_readlineb_w(&rio_client, buf, MAXLINE) > 0)
```

since `=` has lower precedence than `>`, so `n` gets the result of the comparison, which will be either `0` or `1`.  You will need to explicitly group the assignment:

```
(n = Rio_readlineb_w(&rio_client, buf, MAXLINE)) > 0
```

like how it's done in the `Rio_readlineb_w` function.

Assignment has lower precedence than most other operators, so be careful when using an assignment expression in a larger expression.  For example,

```
a = b && c;
```

assigns the result of `b && c` to `a`.  If you want to assign the result of `b` to `a` and compare that to `c`, then you'll need to use parentheses to indicate that:

```
(a = b) && c
```